# Steps to migrate SP 2013 with SQL 2012 from one physical server to another physical server under the same domain

Tags: 2013, migration, sql-server-2012

Steps to migrate SP 2013 with SQL 2012 from one physical server to another physical server under the same DB & domain and using same server name.

Answer (score 0):

I am not even sure if such migration is possible. Best practice is to build a new farm and then migrate the custom solutions and content databases. Then you can use server aliasing to map new server to old one.